# Equivalence between vector bundles with integrable connections to isocrystals

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, connections, crystals

Let $k$ be a perfect field, $W(k)$ its Witt ring, and $K$ the fraction field of $W(k)$. Let $X_k$ be a smooth proper curve over $k$, and let $X_K$ be the schematic generic fibre of a smooth proper lift of $X_k$ to $W(k)$. Let $X_K^{\text{an}}$ be the rigid analytic space associated to $X_K$ (the Raynaud generic fibre of the lift).

I am interested in understanding how the following pair of categories relate to one another:

- The category $\text{VIC}(X_K)$, of vector bundles with an integrable connection on $X_K$.
- The category $\text{Isoc}(X_k/K)$, of vector bundles with an integrable connection on $X_K^{\text{an}}$.

It is clear that there is a functor in the one direction, $\text{VIC}(X_K)\longrightarrow \text{Isoc}(X_k/K)$, sending a vector bundle on $X_K$ to its analytification. Is this functor an equivalence of categories? A reference would be appreciated.

Edit: I believe that through a user's reply suggesting to consider GAGA I understand the line bundle case. There I use a theorem by Grothendieck saying that every analytic closed 1-form is a sum of an algebraic closed 1-form and an analytic exact 1-form, together with the fact that there are no global exact 1-forms, we find that every global closed 1-form is algebraic. On the other side, one sees that a connection on a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ is a global section of $\text{End}(\mathcal{L})\otimes \Omega^{1,\text{an}}_X$. Since $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle, $\text{End}(\mathcal{L})\cong \mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}}$, so that those are the same as global $1$-forms. Since I assumed $X$ is a curve, such a form is closed and is therefore algebraic. Is this correct? I find it a bit confusing because soemhow I thought that any connection should be isomorphic to an algebraic one, but not necessarily be algebraic in the first place.

I am still interested in understanding how to go beyond the case of line bundles, and perhaps even curves, which are 2 things I heavily used in the above argument.

Comment: Yes by basic GAGA stuff.

Comment: There’s a little trick to apply GAGA: since connections are not $\mathcal{O}$-linear, the theorem does not apply directly. But a connection is the same as a splitting of the Atiyah exact sequence, to which GAGA can be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me briefly expand my comment into an answer. As Satan's Minion writes in the comments, this follows from (rigid) GAGA, but I think this fact is not entirely obvious. GAGA gives that analytification is an equivalence of categories between the category of coherent sheaves on $X_K$ (and $\mathscr{O}$-linear maps) and the category of coherent sheaves on $X_K^{\text{an}}$ (and $\mathscr{O}$-linear maps). But an integrable connection on a vector bundle $\mathscr{E}$ is not an $\mathscr{O}$-linear map! So given an analytic integrable connection $$\nabla: \mathscr{E}^{\text{an}}\to \mathscr{E}^{\text{an}}\otimes \Omega^1_{X^{\text{an}}}$$
it does not immediately follow that $\nabla$ is the analytification of an algebraic integrable connection.

The trick is to view an integrable connection as the same as an $\mathscr{O}$-linear splitting of the Atiyah exact sequence $$(*) \qquad0\to \text{End}(\mathscr{E})\to \text{At}(\mathscr{E})\to T_X\to 0.$$ Explicitly, one may view $\text{At}(\mathscr{E})$ as a sheaf of first-order differential operators; then given a connection $\nabla$, one obtains a splitting of the of the Atiyah exact sequence by sending a vector field $v\in T_X(U)$ to $\nabla(v)\in \text{At}(\mathscr{E})(U)$. Now GAGA gives a bijection between ($\mathscr{O}$-linear) splittings of $(*)$ and ($\mathscr{O}$-linear) splittings of its analytification $(*)^{\text{an}}$, as desired.

Comment: I find this very illuminating. Thank you.